# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Transitions with rails 4.1 and transitions gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

My implementation was working with rails version 3.2. I am trying to upgrade my app to rails 4.1 but then I started getting error "uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Transitions". According to transitions gem documentation on github (https://github.com/troessner/transitions) , it should work with rails >=4 without any issue.

code for active_record class with transitions is given below.

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers 
  include ActiveRecord::Transitions

  state_machine do
    state :available
    state :issued

    event :issue do
      transitions :to => :issued, :from => :available
    end
  end
end
```

error I am getting is

```
`<class:Coupon>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Transitions (NameError)
```

Although gem is included

```
gem "transitions", :require => ["transitions", "active_model/transitions"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs say to `include ActiveModel::Transitions`. What you have done is `include ActiveRecord::Transitions`.

Typo maybe??